# Windows manually rename a bunch of pictures

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, rename

I have a folder containing a couple hundred images, and I need to go trough them and (manually) give them appropriate names. I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently, preferably using only the keyboard.

My approach has been to open the folder in windows explorer, set the view to "Extra large icons" and then navigate trough the folders with arrow keys and renaming the pictures with `F2`. The problem with this approach is that the images are still a bit to small for me. Opening every image in the picture viewer is a it too slow.

Is there a better solution? Something build-in would be nice, but I'm also open to program suggestions.

Comment: A good "photo library" program should allow renaming the photos via a shortcut key; I use one on Ubuntu, so I can't provide a good recommendation for Windows.

Comment: @jpaugh Yup, that's pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: Although there might be a built-in workaround, looking for a good [photo app](https://lifehacker.com/5813895/the-best-photo-management-app-for-windows) is your best bet, IMO. That would make an answer off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If the rename operation is mechanical enough, you could use one of the
products in the article
[Best Free File Rename Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-rename-utility.htm).

Some of the utilities allow regular expressions in addition to simple rename.

If you need to see the image in order to rename it, the simplest way is in Windows Explorer to turn on the Preview pane
([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35230-show-hide-preview-pane-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html)),
make Explorer full screen and adjust the size of the Preview pane to the largest practical size.

Comment: Unfortunately the name itself has to be completely manually entered.

Comment: If you cannot work out some rules for the renaming, then manual rename the way you do now is left as the only option. So what are you looking for?

Comment: Going trough the process of opening an image, closing it again and then renaming it gets old really quickly, I'm looking for something where I can quickly view images in fullscreen and instantly rename them by only using the keyboard.

Comment: If you need to see the image in order to rename it, the simplest way is in Windows Explorer to turn on the Preview pane ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35230-show-hide-preview-pane-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html)), make Explorer full screen and adjust the size of the Preview pane to the largest practical size.

Comment: Awesome, I'll accept that as answer if there's nothing better within a day or so!

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just open Windows Picture Manager and use the Rename tab and then scroll through the photos? Quick and Easy